# compare a set of strings from one csv file in another csv file using Unix Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix

I m new to bash Shell scripting. I have a requirement that I have a lookup file (csv) in which there are set of strings in it like below.

file1:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

I have to check whether the strings in file1 are present in the file2.

file2:

```
s.no    desc
1       text5
2       text3
3       text2
4       text9
```

If the the string in file1 is there in file2, then I have to print the output in a new file file3 with the s.no and the string found. Please help.

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: my output file may be like

S.no   desc
3        text2
2        text3

Comment: How are your columns separated? One Space, multiple spaces or one tab?

Comment: it's one tab separated

Comment: With join, sort and bash: `join -1 1 -2 2 -t $'\t' --header <(echo; sort file1) <(sort -t $'\t' -k2,2 file2) -o 2.1,2.2`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
grep --file=file1 file2
```

or

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

From manual page of grep

> ```
>   -f FILE, --file=FILE
>           Obtain  patterns  from  FILE, one per line.  
>           The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is
>           specified by  POSIX.)
> ```

Note: Add `-w` if you want only exact word match. So `footext3bar` will not be matched with `text3`.

Also of `file1` contains regular expressing keywords like `*` or `^` then add `-F` also.

So updated command would be

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

Example

```
bash-4.2$ cat file1
text1
text2
text3
bash-4.2$ cat file2
s.no    desc
1       text5
2       text3
3       text2
4       text9
bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$ grep --file=file1 file2
2       text3
3       text2
```

Comment: Thanks Utsav.  that's working perfectly. if my file2 has a value like below

s.no    desc
1       like text5 is xxxx
2       some text3 is qwe
3       random text2 is dfgg
4       call text9 has phdg

how can i check whether the lookup string is there in the file2? let's say, this is  kind of a error checking mechanism where in we are using a specific error keyword from file1  to search in a log file (file2).

Comment: Cool. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the question could be closed.